# Ways to place $5$ Ps in a $4 × 4$ grid so that each row has at least one P?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> In how many ways can $5$ P's be placed in $16$ identical squares formed by a $4$ × $4$ grid, such that each row has at least one P?

The number of ways of introducing first P will be: $16$ ( let us say the chosen cell is in first row)

Next P has $12$ cells to go in. (let us put that in $2$nd row)

$3$rd P has $8$ cells. (put that in $3$rd row)

$4$th P has $4$ cells. (put that in $4$th row)

And because $4$ cells out of $16$ have been full now, so the final P has $12$ cells to go in.

Making the total number of ways to place = $16 \cdot 12 \cdot 8 \cdot 4 \cdot 12 = 73728$ ways.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please note all $P$'s are identical so if there was no restriction, all you would do is to choose $5$ cells from $16$ cells, which is $ \displaystyle {16 \choose 5}$.

As there are $5$ P's and each row must have at least one $P$, one of the rows will have two $P$'s and rest three rows will have one $P$ each.

For each row with one $P$, there are $4$ columns to choose from and for the row with two $P$, there are $4 \choose 2 ~ $ ways to choose two columns. Also there are $4$ ways to choose the row with two $P$'s.

That leads to $ ~ \displaystyle 4^4 \cdot {4 \choose 2} ~$ ways.

Comment: +1: Nice.  I would have automatically opted for Inclusion-Exclusion, which is clearly inferior, given your answer.

Comment: @user2661923 thank you

Comment: I was using the principle of placing just like we do for placing 3 identical balls  in 4×4 grid such that no 2 balls in the same row or column, where by we go in the order that number of ways of placing first ball is 16, second 9, third 4. ( Assuming that let out of all 16 places for the first ball, we placed it in first row, first column cell. This automatically deletes the entire row, and column and we're left with 9 cells. ). And finally we divide the answer by 6 cuz balls were identical, to get the final answer as 96. I went by the same approach. 

Even if I divide by 5!, it is not 1536.

Comment: @LakshayKhanna if the balls are identical then you should not do $16 \cdot 12 \cdot...$. That will overcount arrangements. If the balls are distinct then yes you should do that. Let me know if it is not clear. I can take a simpler example to explain.

Comment: @MathLover 16*9*4 I mean, sorry for that error. I was using the same logic here.

Comment: @LakshayKhanna Take an example of $2 \times 2$ grid and $2$ identical balls and each row must have a ball. As per your work, it would be $4 \times 2 = 8$ arrangements. But there are only four ways.

Comment: @MathLover Even here, there will be 8 arrangements as you said, but since the balls are identical, we would be doing / 2!, which will still give us 4 ways. My answer of 73728 is total number of ways, but even if I do / 5! for 5 balls, it is not the one you computed and the correct one. I was trying to think along that pattern to be honest.

Comment: ok good. You cannot divide by $5!$ because you first placed $4$ balls as part of $16 \cdot 12 \cdot 8 \cdot 4$ and then $12$ for the last ball. If you were placing $4$ balls, one each in a row then $16 \cdot 12 \cdot 8 \cdot 4$ divided by $4!$ will give you the right result. The problem is that you place the last ball in remaining $12$ places. But in the row that you choose for the last ball, you are again ordering with the ball which is already in that row so you need to divide by $2$ again. So net net you need to divide by $(4! \cdot 2!)$.

Comment: @MathLover Thanks, now I understood this perfectly well. Appreciate your kind help man. Also, would urge you to check a question I posted related to Inequality Doubt over my profile. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we put the $P$'s in the same place you did, but I prefer to start in the fourth row and working up. The result will look the same, yet you did not take this into account in your computations. The order in which we place the $P$'s does not matter, only the cells in which we place them.

We can solve this by looking row per row (you added an example, but did not chose your example 'ad random'):

1. How many ways to put a $P$ **in the first row**?
2. How many ways to put a $P$ **in the second row**?
3. How many ways to put a $P$ **in the third row**?
4. How many ways to put a $P$ **in the fourth row**?
5. How many ways to place the remaining $P$ in the remaining squares?
6. How many ways to switch the two $P$'s that are together in a row? This amount should be divided out, since we double counted those possibilities (as order of placing the $P$'s does not matter).